# JQuery Autocomplete presentation

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete feature.

The Expected data format I'm using is

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

It uses "label" to show in menu and "value" to show in text box.

I want that both menu and textbox will show the "value" and not the label.

This is my code

```
$(function() {
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
    });
});
```

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve my problem,

I Added id for the expected data format and put in it the label value

Instead of

```
 [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

I'm using

```
 [ { label: "value1", value: "value1",id:"Choice1" }, ... ]
```

This way I can save the label value and accomplish what I wanted which is view only the "value"

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to use the `value` in the array.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: ["value1", "value2" ... ]
    });
});
```

Or convert the source.

```
var data = [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ];
$(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: data.map(function() {return this.value;})
    });
});
```

Comment: No , I need the label (save it on the server side)
Just want to view only the value ..

Comment: @johnSmith Label won't be passed to the server side.

Comment: corrent. My bad , I'm saving the label on the client side.. Any way I need the label..